# Cannot convert from 'System.Guid?' to Abp.Application.Services.Dto.EntityDto<System.Guid>

Tags: c#, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to pass the Guid into a method for returning result from the database but I get the following error message

> Cannot convert from 'System.Guid?' to Abp.Application.Services.Dto.EntityDto

Here are the two methods
Method1:

```
        public async Task<ListResultDto<DepartmentDto>> GetAllDepartmentAndReferrerByReferralOrganizationId(EntityDto<Guid> input)
    {
        var filteredDepartment = _departmentRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Include(r => r.Referrer)
            .Where(a => a.ReferralOrganizationId == input.Id);

        var result = await filteredDepartment
        .ToListAsync();

        var lookupTableDtoList = new List<DepartmentDto>();

        //Loop through the department
        foreach (var departmentreferrer in result)
        {
            //Loop through the referrers
            foreach (var item in departmentreferrer.Referrer)
            {
                //get referrer with the id provided
                var referrerValue = GetAllReferrers(item.ReferrerId.Value);
                lookupTableDtoList.Add(new DepartmentDto
                {
                    Name = $"Department: {departmentreferrer.Name} Referrer: {item.ReferrerId}"
                });
            }
        }

        return new ListResultDto<DepartmentDto>(ObjectMapper.Map<List<DepartmentDto>>(lookupTableDtoList));
    }
```

Method 2:

```
        public async Task<ListResultDto<GetReferrerForView>> GetAllReferrers(EntityDto<Guid> input)
    {
        var referrer = _referrerRepository
            .GetAll()
            .Where(r => r.Id == input.Id);

        var result = await referrer
            .ToListAsync();

        return ObjectMapper.Map<ListResultDto<GetReferrerForView>>(result);
    }
```

The line of code with the issue is where I'm trying to pass the Guid into the method e.g. GetAllReferrers(item.ReferrerId). ReferrerId is a nullable Guid e.g. public virtual Guid? ReferrerId { get; set; }

Comment: Exactly. You can't pass a `string` as an `int`. Similarly, you can't pass a nullable `Guid` as an `EntityDto<Guid>`. If you want to call that function, you need to have an `EntityDto<Guid>` to pass to it.

Comment: Cheers mate I changed method 2 to accept Guid instead because i wasn't sure how to pass EntityDto<Guid> into it and got it working that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate an `EntityDto<Guid>` like this:

```
var referrerValue = GetAllReferrers(new EntityDto<Guid>(item.ReferrerId.Value));
```

Comment: Thanks very much @aaron